# How to root Huawei Y210?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting

It runs Android 2.3.6 and has the 2.3.38.6-perf kernel version. I've already tried using SuperOneClick but it doesn't work. :(

I'm rather contented with it ( oh wait, it has this puny internal storage, 120+ mb, but I can live with that ) and I'd rather just leave it alone except for the fact that Huawei saw it fit not to add proxy support. My university network uses proxies so the smartphone is rather useless at school. I tried proxy apps but they all require the phone to be rooted. I hope somebody here can guide me in rooting this phone. Thank you for your time :)

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried SRSRoot as @Izzy suggested, unfortunately, it doesn't work either :(

```
    ---= SRS One-Click-Root v4.3 =---

11:29:51 PM - Starting ADB Server..
11:29:57 PM - Manufacturer: HUAWEI
11:29:58 PM - Model: HUAWEI Y210-0100
11:29:58 PM - Android Version: 2.3.6
11:29:58 PM - Build ID: Y210-0100V100R001C294B837
11:29:58 PM - Board ID: Y210-0100
11:29:58 PM - Chipset Platform: msm7k
11:29:58 PM - Getting OffSets.. : 0x8003 0x8005 (False) 
11:30:00 PM - Query Server for Best Method.. Found Rootkit: 2

    ----= Start Rooting Process.. Please Wait =----

11:30:00 PM [+] Testing exploit: root2a (Please wait it can take some minutes)....
11:30:21 PM [+] Executing root2a exploit Failed, Proceed next...
11:30:21 PM [+] Testing exploit: root4 (please wait..)
11:30:24 PM [+] Device Reboot #1 (Wait till it's started)
11:33:23 PM [+] Executing root4 exploit Failed.  (Root Error: 0)
11:33:23 PM [+] Testing exploit: root4b (please wait..)
11:33:27 PM [+] Device Reboot #1 (Wait till it's started)
11:36:45 PM [+] Device Reboot #2 (Wait till it's started)

11:39:57 PM Auto Root Failed on this device. :( 

11:39:57 PM Rebooting Device and try again...
```

Comment: If it's just for web traffic, you might also want to take a look at [SandroProxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy), which claims to not require root. But as from the description, it's browser only. There's also [Proxymator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faust.proxymator) which doesn't mention root.

Comment: @Izzy Tried them both. Unfortunately, both don't work for me :(

Comment: OK, so back to the root(s): you might want to try [SRSRoot](http://www.srsroot.com/supported), which explicitly mentions to support your device. Let us know if it worked -- best would be to answer your own questions then and describe how you succeeded :)

Comment: @Izzy Woot! Many thanks :D Downloading now... :) I wonder why it never turned up on my searches. Will post the results later :)

Comment: Good luck! Let me know if it worked, so I may convert/sum up the coments to compile an answer from them for the benefit of future "searchers" :) Of course, if you can give a short "How-to" of how you succeeded, feel free to answer your question yourself!

Comment: Tested it already, doesn't work either :( Posted the logs. If we ever figure out how to root this unit though, I think you deserve the rep so I'll leave the answering to you :) Thanks a lot for all the help so far!

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas then. Maybe your BuildID is different from the ones listed as "tested"? :(

Comment: Just checked, same BuildID as the one listed on their page. The site does say that their success rate is only 55%. Wish they'd explain what that means though.

Comment: You may ask them -- I cannot tell :) Two other places I found and you might to check: A [request on rootpros.com](http://rootpros.com/projects/rooting/root-and-flash-new-rom-on-huawei-y210/) (though no bids yet, but you may watch it), and a [strange file on adbrootkit.com](http://www.adbtoolkit.com/rooting/devices/huawei/y210-y220-t8833-u8830-b109/) (no idea whether that is safe, though)...

Comment: Managed to root it and install CWM. Follow [these steps](http://huaweiy210d.blogspot.com).

Comment: @Frank Thanks! Will test it ASAP. Is this for the Y210-0100 model?

Comment: @Frank Tried it. Now my WiFi won't turn on :(

Comment: What ROM are you using btw?
@Izzy I think I didn't do the rooting procedure properly. That's why it didn't work. Will try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was for y210D. You need to flash it stock again and root it with a y210 insecure boot image. You can get the stock ROM [here](https://rapidshare.com/files/2786480610/Y210-0010%20firmware%20%28U8685D%20Android%202.3%20V100R001C17B829_%20China%20Unicom%29.zip).

Comment: Thanks! This one worked. Would you know where I can get the insecure boot image?

Comment: Hi @frank, could you provide a step by step guide? That way people can follow this without leaving the site.

Answer (score 0):

you may [try this](http://www.mediafire.com/?n7z02db5jux22n6) at your own risk. Please do a nand back-up first.

Comment: What is the linky containing? Elaborate more please.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been years but I think people might be interested to know how to root this. I tried again last month using [Framaroot](http://framaroot.net/). You just download the latest version, install the app and run it. Most painless root I've had so far.